ValueError(mismatched columns) is persisting
In my code I was trying to put the data from data table to df table(which is initially empty and only contains header_row as defined by code) by using below code:
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time'] + list(map(str, range(30))))
    for i, time in enumerate(sorted(set(data.index.time))):
     df.loc[i] = [time.strftime(format='%H:%M:%S')] + list(data.at_time(time)['load'].values)[:31]

Now the data table looks(has data for 30 days similiarly) like :
import requests
import csv
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_load_data(date):
    url = 'http://www.delhisldc.org/Loaddata.aspx?mode='
    print('Scraping', date)
    resp = requests.get(url+date) # send a get request to the url, get response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml') # Yummy HTML soup
    table = soup.find('table', {'id':'ContentPlaceHolder3_DGGridAv'}) # get the table from html
    trs = table.findAll('tr') # extract all rows of the table
    if len(trs[1:])!=0: # no need to create csv file, if there's no data, for Aug month of 2017
        csv_filename = 'monthdata.csv'
        with open(csv_filename, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            count=0
            for tr in trs[1:]:
                time, delhi = tr.findChildren('font')[:2]
                writer.writerow([date+' '+time.text, delhi.text])
                count+=1
    if count != 288:
        print('Some of the load values are missing..')
    else:
        print('Done')

# date = date.split('/')
# date.reverse()
''.join(date)
for i in range(31, 0, -1):
    yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(i)
    yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%d/01/2023') #here you can change the date acc. to ur data
    get_load_data(yesterday)


!head monthdata.csv
data = pd.read_csv('monthdata.csv', header=None, names=['datetime', 'load'], index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)

Now I want the df to be something like this(header_row represent time and dates for a month):

Now even though the df and the list(+1 for date) has equal columns, I don't know why this error(for the first code block in this post):
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-10ddc3e7faf7> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time'] + list(map(str, range(30))))
      2 for i, time in enumerate(sorted(set(data.index.time))):
----> 3   df.loc[i] = [time.strftime(format='%H:%M:%S')] + list(data.at_time(time)['load'].values)[:31]
      4 #     # data.at_time(time).plot()
      5 #     # if idx>10: break

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_missing(self, indexer, value)
   2156                     # must have conforming columns
   2157                     if len(value) != len(self.obj.columns):
-> 2158                         raise ValueError("cannot set a row with mismatched columns")
   2159 
   2160                 value = Series(value, index=self.obj.columns, name=indexer)

ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Thanks in advance!

what's the error ? I didn't get it. also that woyuld be helpful if you provide data as code ( your sample df data)

Please [edit] your question to include the error traceback in your question (format it as a code block).

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Note that the [ml] tag is not [machine-learning], which is what you really want.

Oh sorry for tag.

The error here is that the traceback suggests the error being from code block where the numbers of column I have chosen(data table) and the numbers of column(in df) aren't somehow equal(i.e. not 31)(where 30 is each for number of days 0-29, and the one extra is for time). Which I don't understand.
